# What is the limiting factor preventing humans from diving in arbitrarily deep water?

Tags: pressure

The deepest dive record is about 1000 feet if I recall correctly. Most people cannot go below 130 feet. So there is nitrogen narcosis but that is solved by having divers breathe a special mixture that does not have nitrogen. The mechanical pressure is not a problem because most of our body tissue is incompressible and I do not see what stops someone from breathing pressurized air to keep their lungs from collapsing.

So what would happen if someone tried diving at 2000 feet? 10000 feet? What would not work out?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on the Medical SE and what we do here. Please note we have an absolute requirement of demonstration of prior research for questions. On that note - what have you found out about deep diving and consumption of gasses at those depths. BTW I believe 1752 feet/534 m is the current record.

Comment: The lungs aren't the only body compartments that contain compressible gasses. What about the sinuses and GI tract? I would imagine that having your sinuses implode would be a bad thing. Not sure what the effect would be on the GI tract but I would think it would involve having all the gas in your GI tract squeezed out into the peritoneal cavity, and then having it squeezed out from there to everywhere else, and eventually out of your body by abnormal routes. Doesn't sound like a survivable event.